# Manually do a docker import

Tags: docker

Is there a way I can do a manual docker import? I can generate .tar image from docker export on one host computer, I'm wondering if I can manually extract this .tar file somewhere in another host computer's filesystem and have docker recognize the image.

Some something like below

Computer_1
`# docker export CONTAINER_IMAGE -o image.tar
 # scp image.tar Computer_2:~/`

Computer_2
`# tar -xvf image.tar
 # cp -R * /somewhere/docker/stores/container/files/
 # docker images
 # docker run -it CONTAINER_IMAGE`

I know you can just do a docker import CONTAINER_IMAGE but I have a special usecase of needing to do this manually...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's `docker image import`. See https://docs.docker.com/edge/engine/reference/commandline/image_import/